# Table and picture in a Figure

Tags: tables, graphics, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to put a table and an image next to each other in one figure. But the image aligns strangely with the table and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. I tried putting each into an entry of a table (please see code below) but this had no effect.

[image]

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
     Factors $(m)$  &Result \\
     \hline
     1  &4.7875\\
     2  &7.4547\\
     3  &10.2273\\
     4  &13.1177\\
     5  &16.1655\\ 
     6  &19.4081\\ 
     7  &22.5762\\ 
     8  &25.8443\\ 
     9  &29.2642\\ 
     10 &32.8306\\ 
     11 &36.3701\\ 
     12 &39.927\\ 
\end{tabular} &\includegraphics[scale=1.6]{"universe".jpg}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results.}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertically centered or top alingment can be achieved with the help of the `adjustbox` package and the `valign=c` or `=t` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
     Factors \textit{(m)}  &Result \\
     \hline
     1  &4.7875\\
     2  &7.4547\\
     3  &10.2273\\
     4  &13.1177\\
     5  &16.1655\\ 
     6  &19.4081\\ 
     7  &22.5762\\ 
     8  &25.8443\\ 
     9  &29.2642\\ 
     10 &32.8306\\ 
     11 &36.3701\\ 
     12 &39.927\\ 
\end{tabular} 
\quad
\includegraphics[width=5cm,valign=c]{example-image}
\caption{Results.}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\bigskip

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{c|c}
     Factors \textit{(m)}  &Result \\
     \hline
     1  &4.7875\\
     2  &7.4547\\
     3  &10.2273\\
     4  &13.1177\\
     5  &16.1655\\ 
     6  &19.4081\\ 
     7  &22.5762\\ 
     8  &25.8443\\ 
     9  &29.2642\\ 
     10 &32.8306\\ 
     11 &36.3701\\ 
     12 &39.927\\ 
\end{tabular} 
\quad
\includegraphics[width=5cm,valign=t]{example-image}
\caption{Results.}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have also replaced `$(m)$`   by `\textit{(m)}`.